# Username in sign up with Auth firebase not working correctly

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have this code to add a user name with the FirebaseAuth method, and it works, but not the first time. What I mean is that once im in my main activity it says the DisplayName is null, however if I go back and enter again it shows the DisplayName.

```
        firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Dialog.dismiss();
                     if(task.isSuccessful()){

                         FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

                         UserProfileChangeRequest updateProfile = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                                 .setDisplayName(name).build();

                         user.updateProfile(updateProfile);

                         Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Tabbed_Main_Activity.class);

                         Dialog.dismiss();
                         finish();
                         startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand the problem because the posted code shows how DisplayName is set, but not how you are displaying it.  Note that `updateProfile()` is not a synchronous action.  Maybe it's a timing issue.  For debugging, add a completion listener to `updateProfile()` with log output.  That will show you when it is completing relative to other events in your code.

Comment: yup , you are exactly right , it seems that the event triggered after the onCreate . i created a button to refresh and now it works , but i dont really want to do that with a button , u know of any other soultion?